# replacing 3 wire outlet with 5 wire electrical outlet

Tags: electrical

my wall has two hot wires and my new outlet has places for 4 hot wires.  Can I use this outlet and if so do I just leave any one on each side unused

Comment: We'll need some pictures of electrical box, switch and existing hookup. Hopefully you didn't disconnect anything yet. Turn off the power before you remove any covers or switches for the pictures.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the existing box please?

Comment: If you have two **hot** wires, there is something wrong. If you mean two current carrying wires, hot and neutral, and the new outlet has 4 screw terminal, normally two are hot and two neutral and it is real simple as long as you are sure which wire is hot. Normally black or any color but white or green is hot and white is neutral. Extra 2 screws are to split for various reasons or to chain to another outlet.

Comment: Do these receps have TEST or RESET buttons?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0):

Having extra positions is ok but you need to put the wires in the correct locations. 
First turn off the breaker to this outlet and verify it is off.
First hot wires are normally black/red since you said outlet we will go with that.
Connect the black wires to the brass colored sycrews and the white wires to the silver colored screws  the ground wires if there should be connected together and have a pigtail going to the green screw on the outlet , this should get your connections in the right place. 
Now you can turn the power back on and you should be good to go.